# Is there a way I can change the way a list orders its elements?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

*So basically I've created this program that calculates the number of license plates in the current Spanish System, lets the user introduce a certain license plate number (by the way, it's constituted by 4 numbers followed by 3 letters), the program prints its position in the system and lastly, how many there are left after that license plate until the system ends (last one is 9999 ZZZ).

```
 consonant_letters = ['B', 'C', 'D', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'P', 'R', 'S',   
    'T', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    list_of_plates = []
    for x in range(10000):
        if x < 1000 and x > 99:
            x = f"0{x}"
        elif x < 100 and x > 9:
            x = f"00{x}"
        elif x < 10:
            x = f"000{x}"
        for y in consonant_letters:
            for z in consonant_letters:
                for a in consonant_letters:
                    list1 = f'{x} {y}{z}{a}'
                    list_of_plates.append(list1)

    print(list_of_plates)


    license_plate_user = input("Write the license plate: ")
    if license_plate_user in list_of_plates:
        print(list_of_plates.index(license_plate_user))
        license_plates_left = len(list_of_plates) - list_of_plates.index(license_plate_user)
        print(f'There are {license_plates_left} license plates left')
    else:
        print("Wrong values")
```

The ideal order of the license plates would be for example 0000 BBB (It's the first one because we don't use vowels) and the next one 0001 BBB, and once it reaches 9999, then it changes to 0000 BBC and so on. (Basically the order on which they are produced). The problem ocurres when I print the list and I see that it follows a certain pattern, this obviously defeats the whole purpose of my program because the number of position and the number of license plates left don't match reality. The pattern the program follows is this one (this are the last lines of code because when there are so many numbers, in this case 80000000, Python erases the previous lines):

```
ZWS', '9999 ZWT', '9999 ZWV', '9999 ZWW', '9999 ZWX', '9999 ZWY', '9999 ZWZ', '9999 ZXB', '9999 ZXC', '9999 ZXD', '9999 ZXF', '9999 ZXG', '9999 ZXH', '9999 ZXJ', '9999 ZXK', '9999 ZXL', '9999 ZXM', '9999 ZXN', '9999 ZXP', '9999 ZXR', '9999 ZXS', '9999 ZXT', '9999 ZXV', '9999 ZXW', '9999 ZXX', '9999 ZXY', '9999 ZXZ', '9999 ZYB', '9999 ZYC', '9999 ZYD', '9999 ZYF', '9999 ZYG', '9999 ZYH', '9999 ZYJ', '9999 ZYK', '9999 ZYL', '9999 ZYM', '9999 ZYN', '9999 ZYP', '9999 ZYR', '9999 ZYS', '9999 ZYT', '9999 ZYV', '9999 ZYW', '9999 ZYX', '9999 ZYY', '9999 ZYZ', '9999 ZZB', '9999 ZZC', '9999 ZZD', '9999 ZZF', '9999 ZZG', '9999 ZZH', '9999 ZZJ', '9999 ZZK', '9999 ZZL', '9999 ZZM', '9999 ZZN', '9999 ZZP', '9999 ZZR', '9999 ZZS', '9999 ZZT', '9999 ZZV', '9999 ZZW', '9999 ZZX', '9999 ZZY', '9999 ZZZ']
```

When the last lines of code should be in the correct order from 0000 ZZZ to 9999 ZZZ.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Can you give `x`, `y` etc. more descriptive names?

Comment: It seems like making an 80-million element list for this it pretty inefficient. Have you tried just doing the math to figure out where the plate fits?

Answer (score 2):

Since the numbers are incremented before they carry over to letters, you should make the number loop inside the letter loops instead:

```
for y in consonant_letters:
    for z in consonant_letters:
        for a in consonant_letters:
            for x in range(10000):
                if x < 1000 and x > 99:
                    x = f"0{x}"
                elif x < 100 and x > 9:
                    x = f"00{x}"
                elif x < 10:
                    x = f"000{x}"
                list1 = f'{x} {y}{z}{a}'
                list_of_plates.append(list1)
```

You can also use `itertools.product` in place of nested for loops, and use an f-string instead of prepending zeroes conditionally:

```
from itertools import product
list_of_plates = [
    f'{n:04} {"".join(l)}'
    for l, n in product(product(consonant_letters, repeat=3), range(10000))
]
```